# Android Market, are in-app products still useable when publishing has stopped?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, publish

I've tried to find an answer in Googles' help but had no luck.

I'd like to know if in-app products can still be purchased by users that have my app installed, when I stop publishing my app inside the Google Developer Console.

Thanks in advance,

Ruben.

Answer (score 0):

once you publish an app you cannot un-publish it (remove it from the store) so yes all your in-app purchases will still work